# Jquery disable scroll till a certain height is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to recreate the header effect on this page
https://staffhub.office.com/

The page doesn't start scrolling till a certain height is scrolled.
And Im guessing the different sections of the header are just animated in everytime you scroll each section.

Im guessing this can be done in Jquery

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning but I tried experimenting with the scrolltop and scroll method in jquery but no luck at least with the experience I have with jquery

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you guessed right.

```js
$("#idOfScrollingDiv").scroll(scroll1);



function scroll1() {
  if($("#idOfScrollingDiv").scrollTop() > $("#breakpointDiv").position() {
    $("#idOfScrollingDiv").scroll(scroll2);
  }
  else {
    //desired scroll1 behaviour
    //i.e. flip between slides
    //and prevent dfault behaviour
  }
}
function scroll2() {
  if($("#idOfScrollingDiv").scrollTop() <= $("#breakpointDiv").position() {
    $("#idOfScrollingDiv").scroll(scroll1);
  }
  else {
  //normal scrolling
  }  
}
```

Comment: would you be able to make a fiddle, just am confused on where the #breakpointDiv would be located

Comment: Inside of scrolingdiv